# unable video thumbnails and show in a gridview android

Tags: java, android, mediastore

I am developing a sharing app similar to Shareit, Xender. I want to show all the thumbnails of videos in a simple gridview but loading thumbnails takes a lot of time especially if I have more than a 1000 - 2000 videos.
So, I made a program to load each thumbnail on a new thread if it hasn't been loaded and then notify the base adapter.

The Code is :-

```
package com.*.filetransfer.Server.File.Selection.SubFragments;

import android.content.ContentUris;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.media.ThumbnailUtils;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import com.*.filetransfer.R;
import com.*.filetransfer.Strings;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import static com.*.filetransfer.Server.File.Selection.FileSelection.selected_item_counter_down;
import static com.*.filetransfer.Server.File.Selection.FileSelection.selected_item_counter_up;
import static com.*.filetransfer.Server.File.Selection.FileSelection.videoList;

public class VideoGalleryFragment extends Fragment {
    GridView gridView;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridview, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        videoList = new ArrayList<Video>();
        gridView = view.findViewById(R.id.gridview);







        String[] projection = new String[] {
                MediaStore.Video.Media._ID,
                MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
                MediaStore.Video.Media.DURATION,
                MediaStore.Video.Media.SIZE

        };
        String selection = MediaStore.Video.Media.DURATION +
                " >= ?";
        String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {
                String.valueOf(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(5, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS))};
        String sortOrder = MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_ADDED + " DESC";

        try (Cursor cursor = getContext().getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(
                MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                projection,
                selection,
                selectionArgs,
                sortOrder
        )) {
            // Cache column indices.
            int idColumn = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media._ID);
            int nameColumn =
                    cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME);
            int durationColumn =
                    cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DURATION);
            int sizeColumn = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.SIZE);

            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                // Get values of columns for a given video.
                long id = cursor.getLong(idColumn);
                String name = cursor.getString(nameColumn);
                int duration = cursor.getInt(durationColumn);
                long size = cursor.getLong(sizeColumn);
                Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                        MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, id);

                // Stores column values and the contentUri in a local object
                // that represents the media file.





                videoList.add(new Video(contentUri, name, duration, size, null, false, false));

            }
            gridView.setAdapter(new GalleryGridViewAdapter(requireContext(), videoList){
                @Override
                public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


                    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
                    if (imageView == null){
                        imageView = new ImageView(requireContext());
                        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(300,300));
                        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
                        imageView.setPadding(20,20,20,20);

                    }

                    if (( (Video) getItem(position)).isChecked()){
                        imageView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.aqua));
                    }
                    else{
                        imageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                    }


                    if (((Video)getItem(position)).getThumbnail() == null && (!((Video)getItem(position)).isImageLoading())){
                        ((Video)getItem(position)).setImageLoading(true);
                        new Thread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
                                Cursor cursor1 = requireContext().getContentResolver().query(((Video)getItem(position)).getUri(), filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                                cursor1.moveToFirst();
                                int columnIndex = cursor1.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                                String picturePath = cursor1.getString(columnIndex);
                                cursor1.close();

                                Bitmap bitmap = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(picturePath, MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
                                ((Video)getItem(position)).setThumbnail(bitmap);
                                ((Video)getItem(position)).setImageLoading(true);
                                try {
                                    requireActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void run() {
                                            notifyDataSetChanged();
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                                catch (IllegalStateException ignored){

                                }
                            }
                        }).start();
                    }
                    if (((Video)getItem(position)).getThumbnail() != null)
                        imageView.setImageBitmap(((Video)getItem(position)).getThumbnail());


                    return imageView;
                }

            });


        }

        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                if (!videoList.get(position).isChecked()) {
                    videoList.get(position).setChecked(true);
                    selected_item_counter_up();
                    Log.e(Strings.TAG, String.valueOf(videoList.get(position).getSize()));
                    try {
                        ((ImageView) view).setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.aqua));
                    } catch (Exception e) {

                    }
                }
                else{
                    videoList.get(position).setChecked(false);
                    selected_item_counter_down();
                    try {
                        ((ImageView) view).setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                }
            }
        });


    }
}

class GalleryGridViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private List<Video> videos;
    private Context context;

    public GalleryGridViewAdapter(Context context, List<Video> videoList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.videos = videoList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return videos.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return videos.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

The static methods and variable imported on top are :-

```
public static List<Video> videoList;
public static void selected_item_counter_up(){
        selected_counter++;
        view_counter.setText("Selected (" + selected_counter + ")");
    }
    public static void selected_item_counter_down(){
        selected_counter--;
        view_counter.setText("Selected (" + selected_counter + ")");
    }
```

My video class is simple as follows:-

```
package com.*.filetransfer.Server.File.Selection.SubFragments;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;

public class Video {
    private final Uri uri;
    private final String name;
    private final int duration;
    private final long size;
    private Bitmap thumbnail;
    private boolean isImageLoading;
    private boolean isChecked;

    public Video(Uri uri, String name, int duration, long size, Bitmap bitmap, boolean isImageLoading, boolean isChecked) {
        this.uri = uri;
        this.name = name;
        this.duration = duration;
        this.size = size;
        this.thumbnail = bitmap;
        this.isImageLoading = isImageLoading;
        this.isChecked = isChecked;
    }

    public boolean isChecked() {
        return isChecked;
    }

    public boolean isImageLoading() {
        return isImageLoading;
    }

    public Uri getUri() {
        return uri;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getDuration() {
        return duration;
    }

    public long getSize() {
        return size;
    }

    public Bitmap getThumbnail() {
        return thumbnail;
    }


    public void setThumbnail(Bitmap thumbnail) {
        this.thumbnail = thumbnail;
    }

    public void setImageLoading(boolean imageLoading) {
        isImageLoading = imageLoading;
    }

    public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
        isChecked = checked;
    }
}
```

The problem I am facing is, if the user scrolls too fast mostly all of the thumbnails are mixed up and some load multiple times. Can someone spot the flaw and correct it.

If you can please suggest an alternative way to load and show thumbnails of media on device, if possible seperated by date as I am unable to figure out how to do it

**EDIT**

I switched to recyclerview and it scrolls very smoothly but It is scrolling to top for some reason. Here is the updated code:-

```
package com.*.filetransfer.Server.File.Selection.SubFragments;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.sugarsnooper.filetransfer.R;
import com.*.filetransfer.Server.File.Selection.Media;
import com.*.filetransfer.Server.Send_Activity;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Map;

import static com.*.filetransfer.Server.File.Selection.FileSelection.imageList;


public class Photos extends Fragment {
    RecyclerView gridView;
    GridAdapter ga = new GridAdapter();
    private int max_padding = 20;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridview, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);


        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                imageList = new ArrayList<>();

                for (Map.Entry<String, Long> entry : Send_Activity.readableRoots.getImages().entrySet())
                {
                    File file = new File(entry.getKey());
                    imageList.add(new Media(Uri.fromFile(file), file.getName(), file.length(), entry.getValue()));
                }
                new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        gridView = view.findViewById(R.id.gridview);
                        gridView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(requireContext(), 3));
                        gridView.setAdapter(ga);
                        gridView.addItemDecoration(new SpacesItemDecoration(30));
                        

                    }
                });
            }
        }).start();

        

    }

    
    class SpacesItemDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {
        private int space;

        public SpacesItemDecoration(int space) {
            this.space = space;
        }

        @Override
        public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view,
                                   RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
            outRect.left = space;
            outRect.right = space;
            outRect.bottom = space;

            // Add top margin only for the first item to avoid double space between items
            if (parent.getChildLayoutPosition(view) == 0) {
                outRect.top = space;
            } else {
                outRect.top = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    class GridAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<GridAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

            View layout = LayoutInflater.from(requireActivity()).inflate(R.layout.grid_item, parent, false);
            return new MyViewHolder(layout);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int i) {
            if (((Media) getItem(i)).isChecked()) {
                    holder.ivparent.setPadding(max_padding, max_padding, max_padding, max_padding);
                    holder.ivparent.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#777777"));
                }
                else{
                    holder.ivparent.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
                    holder.ivparent.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00777777"));
                }

            Glide.with(requireActivity()).fromUri().dontAnimate().load(((Media) getItem(i)).getUri()).into(holder.imageView);
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return imageList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public void onViewRecycled(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder) {
            super.onViewRecycled(holder);
            holder.recycle();
        }

        public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            LinearLayout ivparent;
            ImageView imageView;
            public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                 imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
                 ivparent = itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_parent);
            }


            public void recycle() {
                Glide.clear(imageView);
            }
        }

        public Object getItem(int i) {
            return imageList.get(i);
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- To achieve the same behavior I used **Recyclerview + GridLayoutManager**.
- And loaded thumbnail from video uris using Glide inside `onBindViewHolder`.
- So thumbnail for only items that are currently loaded in the screen gets created, and it handles async loading and clearing the views

  ```
  @Override
  public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
         // Code for loading thumbnail using video file path
        Glide.with(context)
             .load(Uri.fromFile(new File(videoFilePath)))
             .thumbnail(0.5f)
             .into(imageView);
  }
  ```

Comment: Can you explain any advantage of using recycled view over gridview?

Comment: Recyclerview helps with recycling of views. Only views which are visible in the screen gets inflated and when new views come into view, new inflations don't happen.

You can use gridview also and call this Glide method when you set data in your views.

Comment: Hey, I implemented your code yesterday, and am facing a wierd problem. the problem is that sometimes the recyclerview scrolls to top by itself. I am adding the code to my question.

Comment: This would happen if you are setting the adapter again in the recyclerview. Check if onViewCreated is called multiple times when this issue happens. 
I initialise my recyclerview and set adapter in onActivityCreated. Then data loading begins and new data is set in adapter using a method.

Comment: onViewCreated is not getting called multiple times I just test tested it. Do you see anything wrong with the code?